# Collapse siblings causing "stutter"

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidebar menu with multiple li with class collapse.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Management"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cogs"></i> Company Management <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <ul id="Management" class="collapse">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Management Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Employees</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Locations</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Accounting"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dollar"></i> Accounting <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <ul id="Accounting" class="collapse">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Pay Current Invoice</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Search for Invoice</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Billing History</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

I am using this jquery code:

```
$(function () {
            $(".collapse").hide();

            $("a").click(function () {
                $(".collapse").slideUp('fast');
                $(this).next(".collapse").slideDown("fast");
            });
        });
```

It works fine, however, it creates a "stutter", meaning it tries to open the new collapse, stops, closes the open collapse and then displays the new open li.

Is there something simple that I'm missing to avoid that stutter-step?

New to jquery so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look into the callback for slideup ".slideUp( "fast", function() {
     $(this).next(".collapse").slideDown("fast");
  });" so it won't  open the next one until the first one is closed.

Comment: DasBeasto - When I tried that none of the drop downs would open at all.  I did find that my initial 'hide'  was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write your own jQuery. You do need to add the `data-parent` attribute, however, and you need the `.panel` class on your list items:

```
<ul id="topmenu">
    <li class="panel">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#topmenu" ... >
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/t26jr7fk/)**

Note that I've applied some CSS to override the margin that `.panel` gets. As to why your original attempt was troublesome... maybe it was colliding with Bootstrap's `collapse()` method.

Comment: great solution only the "panel" class messes with my existing css requiring customization.

Comment: I think I'd still find that preferable to writing redundant scripts. YMMV.